# Database Replication from firebird to postgres

Tags: java, postgresql, cron, firebird, database-replication

I have 2 databases, Firebird and PostgreSQL. And I need to replicate the Firebird information to PostgreSQL when updating the Firebird database. What is the best way to do that? I'm using cron for that task, but would there be another way with more performance and faster in real time updated?

The cron job is launched every 30 minutes, and the application for that is implemented in Java.